# Ada visitor design pattern and generics

Tags: generics, ada, visitor-pattern

I'm implementing a visitor pattern and I have some elements that I could implement using generics, but the GNAT compiler complains with the generic type.
I have a solution using generic mix-ins but its less intuitive.

How can I solve it?

I provide the following minimal reproducibable example:

1. visitors.ads

```
with ConcreteElements;
with Instantiation;

package Visitors is

  type Visitor_t is interface;

  procedure pVisit (this : in Visitor_t;
                    element : ConcreteElements.ConcreteElement_t) is abstract;

  procedure pVisit (this : in Visitor_t;
                    element : Instantiation.GenericElement_t) is abstract;

end Visitors;
```

2. elements.ads

```
limited with Visitors;

package Elements is

  type Element_t is abstract tagged null record;

  procedure pAccept
    (this : in Element_t;
     visitor : in Visitors.Visitor_t'Class) is abstract;

end Elements;
```

3. concreteelements.ads/adb

```
limited with Visitors;
with Elements;

package ConcreteElements is

  type ConcreteElement_t is new Elements.Element_t with null record;

  overriding
  procedure pAccept
    (this : in ConcreteElement_t;
     visitor : in Visitors.Visitor_t'Class);

end ConcreteElements;
```

```
with Visitors;

package body ConcreteElements is

  procedure pAccept
    (this : in ConcreteElement_t;
     visitor : in Visitors.Visitor_t'Class) is
  begin
    visitor.pVisit(this);
  end pAccept;

end ConcreteElements;
```

4. genericelements.ads/adb

```
with Elements;
limited with Visitors;

generic
  type Parent_t (<>) is abstract new Elements.Element_t with private;
package GenericElements is

  type GenericElement_t is new Parent_t with null record;

  overriding
  procedure pAccept (this : in GenericElement_t;
                     visitor : in Visitors.Visitor_t'Class);

end GenericElements;
```

```
with Visitors;

package body GenericElements is

  procedure pAccept (this : in GenericElement_t;
                     visitor : in Visitors.Visitor_t'Class) is
  begin
    visitor.pVisit(this);
  end pAccept;

end GenericElements;
```

5. instantiation.ads

```
with GenericElements;
with Elements;

package instantiation is new GenericElements
  (Parent_t => Elements.Element_t);
```

The compiler complains in the body of 4), at line 9:

> expected type "instantiation.GenericELement_t" defined at genericelements.ads:8
>
> > found type "GenericElements.GenericElement_t" defined at genericelements.ads:8

**My solution** is to perform a mix-in, making GenericElement_t abstract, thus this would be 1), 4) and 5):

1)

```
with ConcreteElements;
with Instantiation;

package Visitors is

  type Visitor_t is interface;

  procedure pVisit (this : in Visitor_t;
                    element : ConcreteElements.ConcreteElement_t) is abstract;

  procedure pVisit (this : in Visitor_t;
                    element : Instantiation.Instantiation_t) is abstract;

end Visitors;
```

4. 

```
with Elements;

generic
  type Parent_t (<>) is abstract new Elements.Element_t with private;
package GenericElements is

  type GenericElement_t is abstract new Parent_t with null record;

end GenericElements;
```

5. 

```
private with GenericElements;
limited with Visitors;
with Elements;

package instantiation is 

  type Instantiation_t is new Elements.Element_t with private;

  overriding
  procedure pAccept (this : in Instantiation_t;
                     visitor : Visitors.Visitor_t'Class);

private

  package instantiation_pck is new GenericElements 
    (Parent_t => Elements.Element_t);

  type Instantiation_t is new instantiation_pck.GenericElement_t with null record;

end instantiation;
```

```
with Visitors;

package body instantiation is

  procedure pAccept (this : in Instantiation_t;
                     visitor : Visitors.Visitor_t'Class) is
  begin
    visitor.pVisit(this);
  end pAccept;


end instantiation;
```

Can I implement correctly the first option or I shall implement it using mix-ins?

Thank you in advance and sorry for the ammount of code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it the way you originally want.  Generic instantiations in Ada are all separate types, even if it is the same inputs to the generic (unlike say in C++ where the types would be the same).  Therefore the parameter in your Visitors package of type Instantiation.GenericElement_t would be technically different than the version inside the generic which doesn't have a specific type yet (since it is inside the generic without an instantiation).

I don't know if the mixin is the only strategy or not for sure.  There may be other ways to reorganize it to work better, but I don't know of any off hand, so you may be stuck with the mixin if no one else has a better plan.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jere. For me the mix-in its ok, but for some unexperienced reviewer may be weird and difficult to understand